# PHP - replace character referring to another character sequence in the array

Tags: php, arrays, replace, character, sequence

i have

> $a='1024,1025,0000|1020,0000|';
>   $b='1024,1025,0000,1020,0000,';

i want replace commas (,) in $b with (|) so that $ b is equal to $ a
like this

Output :

> $b='1024,1025,0000|1020,0000|';

How to make it with PHP

**Edit Question**

in my case, I want that $b will be having the sequence (,) and (|) as $a. in focus is (,) and (|) position, another example of data

> $a='1024,1025,1234|1020,0000|';
>   $b='1024,1025,3321,1020,2345,';

Output :

> $b='1024,1025,3321|1020,2345|';

How to make it with PHP, thanks to the help

regards,

Comment: What you're saying is you want `$b` to equal to `$a` (if not, pick a better example)?

Comment: @TimCooper yes, i have such a case, can you give an idea for me ?

Comment: problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make $b exactly as $a, You've to use below code that uses str_replace() function.

```
$b=str_replace("0000,","0000|",$b);
```

Comment: where did I put that this refers to the $a

Comment: and what if it does not always 0000

Comment: I've a query, Whether that 4 digit number sequence count always will be 5 & the position of comma (,) to be replaced from $b are always in 3rd & 5th place?

Comment: no, 4 digit serial number does not always count 5 & position comma (,) to be replaced from $b are not always in place 3 & 5

Comment: There is some confusion exists regarding your requirement! If you've both $a and $b available means, why do you go for a replacement! Huh?

Comment: M Jhon, relates to the data so that anything can happen, I am trying to find the sequence (|) at $a with strpos and $b will change in the sequence (|) is found in $a and then i replace it, i'm using this function for replace : `function replace_element($str,$search,$replace,$num) {
    $num = $num - 1;
    $pieces = str_split($str);
    if($pieces[$num] == $search) {
        $pieces[$num] = $replace;
    }
    return implode('',$pieces);
}` and problem has been solved, thanks for attention.